# RecyclerView getting wrong position When Apply Search with Search Filter

Tags: java, android

I use `RecyclerView` and I have implemented Search Filter on it and i am facing a problem here

After I search when I press on item I get wrong position not one I searched it please help me to solve this problem

For example item number 2 name "Android" after search "android" the  position go number one .. why get this problem ? .. thank you

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
    private Context mContext;


    public MyAdapter(List<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context mContext) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = mContext;


    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (position == 0) {


                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"iOS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                if (position == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Android",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(itemList.getTitle());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(itemList.getDescription());
        holder.txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Display option menu
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.txtOptionDigit);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.mnu_item_save:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved " + listItems.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case R.id.mnu_item_delete:
                                //Delete item
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted " + listItems.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                listItems.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private  Button buttoncalling;
        public TextView txtTitle;
        public TextView txtDescription;
        public TextView txtOptionDigit;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);
            buttoncalling  = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bbbbbbbbbb);
            buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

Filter

```
   TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().equals("")){
                initAdapter();
            } else {
                searchItem(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

    private void initAdapter(){
        adapter.listItems.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            listItems.add(new RecyclerItem("Item " + (i + 1), "Welcome to Torisan channel, this is description of item " + (i+1)));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void searchItem(String itemname){
        int resultCount = 0;
        adapter.listItems.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempListItems.size(); i++){
            if (tempListItems.get(i).getTitle().contains(itemname)){
                listItems.add(new RecyclerItem("Item " + (i + 1), "Welcome to Torisan channel, this is description of item " + (i+1)));
                resultCount ++;
            }
        }
        if (resultCount == 0){
            showToast();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void showToast() {
        // Set the toast and duration
        int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 1000;
        mToastToShow = Toast.makeText(this, "No results found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        // Set the countdown to display the toast
        CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
        toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 1000 /*Tick duration*/) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mToastToShow.show();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                mToastToShow.cancel();
            }
        };

        // Show the toast and starts the countdown
        mToastToShow.show();
        toastCountDown.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your filter method?

Comment: This Happen Because when you filter your List then new List is created in which "Android" item is number one.. And please share the filter method. So that we can help you more. Thanks

Comment: It is not giving you wrong position. Its because after every search, adapter list resets as per your filter.

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
    private Context mContext;


    public MyAdapter(List<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context mContext) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mContext = mContext;


    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(getAdapterPosition());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               final int position =    Integer.parse(v.getTag().toString());
                if (position == 0) {


                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"iOS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                if (position == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Android",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(itemList.getTitle());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(itemList.getDescription());
        holder.txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Display option menu
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.txtOptionDigit);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.mnu_item_save:
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved " + listItems.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case R.id.mnu_item_delete:
                                //Delete item
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted " + listItems.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                listItems.remove(position);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private  Button buttoncalling;
        public TextView txtTitle;
        public TextView txtDescription;
        public TextView txtOptionDigit;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            txtOptionDigit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);
            buttoncalling  = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bbbbbbbbbb);
            buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempListItems.size(); i++) {
    if (listItems.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName().equals(tempListItems.get(i).getName())) {
        int selectedPos = i;  //SelectedPos is that index
        break;
    }
}
```